# How to Edit a File Text in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a file now in that i want to update the value of variable.How can we do this .
**File Content:**

```
<Config>
 NUM1 =  8
 AMV1 =  8
 AMV2 =  8
 DEF2 =  8
 DGF =  8
 </Config>
```

Now in this i want to change the value of `NUM1` how can we do this in Perl.

Comment: You know, that's not really how StackOverflow is supposed to work. We're not going to just write code to your specifications. Generally, we like you to show some effort in solving the problem yourself and we'll help you over any specific issues that you're having.

Comment: Fortunately this code has already been written.  `Config::General` reads this file format nicely, and it's `save_file` method will do the writing.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please
[edit] your question to show the code you have written so
far and where you are stuck, then we can try to help with
specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it directly from the command line with a one-liner:

```
perl -i~ -pe 's/^(\s*NUM1 )=.*/$1=NewValue/' config-file
```

- `-i~` changes the file "in place", leaving a backup with the tilde appended
- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints it
- `s///` is a substitution
- `()` create a capture group in a regex, the first capture group can be referenced from the replacement part as `$1`

In a script, you need to add replace `-p` with the actual code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<>) {
    s/^(\s*NUM1 )=.*/$1=NewValue/;
    print;
}
```

Save to `update-config`, run as `update-config config-file > new-config`.

Or, if you want to handle even the opening of the file yourself:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $filename = 'config-file';
my $newfile  = "$filename.new";
my $backup   = "$filename~";

open my $IN, '<', $filename or die $!;
open my $OUT, '>', $newfile or die $!;
while (<$IN>) {
    s/^(\s*NUM1 )=.*/$1=NewValue/;
    print {$OUT} $_;
}
close $OUT or die $!;
rename $filename, $backup or die $!;
rename $newfile, $filename or die $!;
```

Comment: I want this to put in a perl script how can we do this inside a perl script

Comment: @Developer: Check the update.

Comment: It is not updating the file value